# Wildcard Subdomain on MAMP Pro with Laravel 4.2.*

Tags: laravel-4, subdomain, mamp-pro

I have this domain-specific routing:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.mysystem.dev'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function($account)
    {
        return sprintf('Hello %s', $account);
    });
});
```

I don't want to make the subdomains myself, but give all subdomains (`*.mysystem.dev`) to Laravel to handle.

In my MAMP Pro panel I tried this in the Extended tab, field `Additional parameters for <VirtualHost>`:

```
ServerAlias mysystem.dev *.mysystem.dev
```

Yet it doesn't work.

If I add an Alias Name in the General Tab like `allendar.mysystem.dev` it will direct me to the `mysystem.dev` directive, yet Laravel doesn't pick it up as it were a subdomain of `.mysystem.dev`. I think it has something to do with the Alias not actually being a subdomain, but I'm not sure.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

i resolved this problem by some docs on the web:

This require two steps;
First step is to set up dnsmasq with `.local` subdomain. It will listen to every domain within `.local` 4.eg `*.something.local.` but also `http://local` or `stackoverflow.local` You can 
do same with `.dev`

`brew install dnsmasq`

`cd $(brew --prefix); mkdir etc; echo 'address=/.local/127.0.0.1' > etc/dnsmasq.conf`

`sudo cp -v $(brew --prefix dnsmasq)/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons`

`sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist`

`sudo mkdir /etc/resolver`

`sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolver/local'`

Next step is to configure MAMP to deliver any wildcard into subdomain via main config;
Do this:

Follow These Steps

1. Open up MAMP Pro
2. Go to: File -> Edit Template -> Apache -> httpd.conf
3. Search for this line: ServerName MAMP_VirtualHost_ServerName_MAMP
4. Add this directly below it: ServerAlias *.MAMP_VirtualHost_ServerName_MAMP
5. Add `ServerAlias *.yourdomain.local` onto Apache under  directive in added host
6. Restart MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add wildcard subdomains, because they are not in /etc/hosts.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57160/wp-multisite-development-with-mamp-pro-and-wildcard-subdomains-not-really-worki

You have to add them manually, like 2 -3 for testing, or create seperate test1.mysystem.dev and  test2.mysystem.dev just for testing.